# Does Protobuf-net tag numbers have performance implications

Tags: .net, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I remember once reading that the tags used for protobuf-net have performance implications but I don't seem to find that post...

for example, using ProtoInclude(1001, typeof(MyType)) will be not efficient as ProtoInclude(101, typeof(MyType))

and same goes for members etc.

Can you please shed some light on this and maybe give some best practice?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

field numbers in protocol buffers are encoded using "varint" encoding. In "varint", the MSB is a continuation bit, so there are only 7 bits per byte for data. However, the first 3 bits are reserved for the field type; so that means:

- a 4 bit field number can be stored (including the field type) in a single byte
- an 11 bit field number can be stored in 2 bytes
- an 18 bit field number can be stored in 3 bytes

and so on.

Decimal 101 is a 7 bit number; decimal 1001 is a 10 bit number; so both will take 2 bytes per field. That's basically how the overhead works here. Other than that: it doesn't matter.